# Inserting image in attribute table and unable to save edits operation attempted on empty geometry

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, attribute-table, windows-8

I have been trying to associate/insert images in an attribute table. I have created a field called pictures and data type is Raster. ( I have used **[this resource video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0AWFvU6no_Q)** to do the task)

Once I load the picture in the attribute table, every thing is ok. I can see the picture in the attribute table. But once I want to save the edits, I am getting this error: unable to save edits operation attempted on empty geometry.

ArcGIS Desktop 10.1 (Advanced), Windows 8

Comment: What type of geodatabase are you using?  The video seems to use a Personal Geodatabase stored in Access.  Have you tried using Attachments in a File Geodatabase?  I know they work well.

Comment: Thanks PolyGeo for taking the time to respond. yes i am using File Geodatabase. Not personal Geodatabase. If i get you well, File Geodatabase also works with using attachments right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you investigate (and use) [Attachments](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m90000000r000000) with your File Geodatabase(s) instead of the method from that video that seems to be using Personal Geodatabases.